# rails float type number does not work right

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  describe "common methods" do

    it "should get right settlement percent" do
      contract = Contract.new
      contract.settlement_percent = 1.1 / 100.0
      contract.settlement_percent.to_f.should == 0.011 
      contract.settlement_percent.to_s.should == "0.011"
    end

  end

1) Contract common methods should 
 Failure/Error: contract.settlement_percent.to_f.should == 0.011
 expected: 0.011,
      got: 0.011000000000000001 (using ==)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `be_close` method to account for this approximation issue. Just pass it the value and how close you want the comparison to be.

Something like this should work for you:

```
contract.settlement_percent.to_f.should be_close(0.011, 0.0001)
```

[A little more on be_close here...](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000153)

Answer (score 0):

Base-10 floating point values are always approximated since they're encoded in binary. You shouldn't expect values to be that precise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison/17341#17341)